# @staticmethod, can anyone explain the following python code?

Tags: python

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def a():
        return "a"


class B1(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def a():
        return "b"


class B2(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class C1(B1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def a():
        return super(C1, C1).a()


class C2(B1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def a():
        return super(B1, B1).a()
```

So here's a tricky thing I'm having understanding.

`B2().a()`  returns a, even though B2 doesn't have a method called a().

How come?

Also, I don't quite understand how staticmethod differs from the other methods.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `staticmethod`. It's just regular inheritance.

Comment: What if you remove B1 and the Cs from the code? You get closer to a [mcve]! That said, what part of `staticmethod`'s function puzzles you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every class here inherits (directly or indirectly) from `A` (that's what `class B2(A):` is telling you).

Since they inherit from `A`, they have access to `A`'s methods. All the `@staticmethod` decorator does is suppress passing `self` to the method implicitly when it's called on an instance, so that `A.a()` and `A().a()` work the same; similarly, `B2.a()` and `B2().a()` work the same way, invoking `A.a()`.

Comment: Attributes are also inherited, though there are none in this case.